# iOS iAP Hosted content download not working

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, iap-hosted-content

I have several non-consumable iAPs for my app. The first version of the app included the appropriate content inside the app bundle, so the iAPs were just to unlock the areas that can access the content.
I'm working on a second version of the app and this time the content will be downloaded when the user makes the purchase.
I created new versions of the iAPs (IMPORTANT: New versions of the same iAPs, but this time adding "Hosted Content", they are not brand new iAPs), the hosted content was uploaded successfully, and the iAPs status is "Ready to Submit".
Everything was working and the content was downloaded to the device, until 1 week ago, when for some reason when I tested, the purchase is successful but the content is not being downloaded. 
Using a breakpoint when creating the `SKPayment` object, I can see it has downloadable content:

```
(lldb) po product.downloadable
YES
```

Even the version is the same as in iTunes Connect:

```
(lldb) po product.downloadContentVersion
1.1
```

But when handling the transaction inside `-paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`, it has no `SKDownload` objects:

```
(lldb) po transaction.transactionState
SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased

(lldb) po transaction.downloads
<__NSArrayM 0x13e1d38a0>(

)
```

I'm using a TestFlight Sandbox user and it shows [Environment: Sandbox] when performing the purchase, so I know I'm not on the production environment.

What is going on? Why it suddenly stopped working? Did Apple recently changed something? This is driving me crazy.
Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Same here - fully operational code (Objective-C) with iAP+hosted content suddenly does not work (same issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally have an answer for this. Turns out, this was a bug from Apple. 
I requested a Technical Support Incident about this, and an Apple engineer responded:

> It’s unfortunate that this is a known issue. Until it’s resolved, I can only suggest that you submit a bug report and prepare an external TestFlight build, if the QA team asks for one.

But the best part is that today, thank God Almighty, the same engineer came back and said:

> You should now find that this issue should no longer be happening.

I just tested and I can confirm the bug is gone.